# VSTS Node API - can't use the Identities API

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm having some trouble with the [VSTS Node Api](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api/) - specifically, the [Identities API](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api/blob/master/api/IdentitiesApi.ts).

I've already successfully used the Git API to perform actions like retrieving a list of repositories:

```
// From ./functions/functions.js
module.exports.getRepos = async function (vstsWebApi) {
  var gitApi = vstsWebApi.getGitApi();
  var repos = await gitApi.getRepositories();
  return repos;
}
```

Then, elsewhere, the following works as expected and the object representing the Git repositories is logged to the console:

```
let funcs = require("./functions/functions.js");
let vsts = require("vso-node-api");
let accessTokenPromise = VSS.getAccessToken();

accessTokenPromise.then(token => {
  let bearerHandler = vsts.getBearerHandler(token.token);
  let collectionUri = VSS.getWebContext().collection.uri;
  let connect = new vsts.WebApi(collectionUri, bearerHandler);
  let apiCallPromise = funcs.getRepos(connect);
  apiCallPromise.then(
    result => {
      console.log(result);
    }
  )
})
```

However, if I try to do something similar and use the Identities API to `listGroups`:

```
module.exports.getGroups = async function (vstsWebApi) {
  var identitiesApi = vstsWebApi.getIdentitiesApi();
  var groups = await identitiesApi.listGroups();
  return groups;
}
```

Changing the promise to getGroups instead of getRepos...

```
...
let apiCallPromise= funcs.getGroups(connect);
apiCallPromise.then(
  result => {
    console.log(result);
  }
...
```

...I get this error:

```
Error: Failed to find api location for area: IMS id: 5966283b-4196-4d57-9211-1b68f41ec1c2
```

I'm trying this on my personal VSTS account, so I should be the owner/Administrator - and I'd expect a different error if my access was denied via a permissions issue. I've tried different values for the `collectionUri`, like including the project name (my-account.visualstudio.com/ProjectABC) but that doesn't work either. I've also tried other Identities API calls, such as `getSelf`, with the same result.

Comment: Try to capture the request through Fiddler tool and post the detail here.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Fiddler, but it doesn't look like I can view the decrypted raw traffic. If I try to make Fiddler decrypt the HTTPS requests, I'm not allowed to bypass the resulting security warning since VSTS uses HTTP Strict Transport Security. Do you happen to know if the Identities API detailed in the VSTS Node API has a REST API equivalent? I don't seem to see the Identities API in the "REST API Overview for VSTS" documentation.

Comment: With the Git API, I was able to play around with it here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/overview and that corresponds to the Node API here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api/blob/master/api/GitApi.ts but with the Identities API I haven't found any equivalent to https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api/blob/master/api/IdentitiesApi.ts

Comment: I don't find the related REST API too and this VSTS node api is still in preview. (Can reproduce this issue)

Comment: I was starting to get that feeling that it had to do with the preview state of the API. I appreciate you helping out and putting another pair of eyes on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submit a feedback here: [Identities API in VSTS-Node-API preview version](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/163711/identities-api-in-vsts-node-api-preview-version.html), you can vote and follow it.